# Bash Script -- logname validation

Tags: shell

How do I validate that the LOGNAME is present in a bash script

```
if [`logname`]; then
    echo -e \\t "-- Logname : `logname`" >> $normal_output_filename
fi
```

The above gives me an error line 76: [logname]: command not found

Comment: Maybe add line numbers next time if you refer to a specific line number later? TIA

Comment: The other lines are unimportant I just copied and pasted the error which happened to have the line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
if [ -e /bin/logname ]; then
    LOGNAME=`logname`
    echo -e \\t "-- Logname : ${LOGNAME}" >> $normal_output_filename
fi
```

Actually, instead of using backtics it's better to use command substitution, namely:

```
LOGNAME=$(logname)
```

Using this syntax allows you to easily nest command substitutions without having to worry about layers of backslashes which is the case when using the older backtic syntax.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ `logname` ]; then
    echo -e \\t "-- Logname : `logname`" >> $normal_output_filename
fi
```

Mind the space between [ and `.

Answer (score 1):

When using backticks like this:

```
   `logname`
```

you execute the command `logname`. I guess it is not intended, is it?

Take a look at [command substitution in Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04).

Comment: if [logname]; then
Does not evaluate true or false - I will try the other suggestions but thanks for the link, it was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the "which" command to see if the specified command exists:

```
if which logname >/dev/null 2>&1; then
     #do something here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. Another answer. Not quite sure if fits you, but:

```
if test -n `logname`; then
    echo -e \\t "-- Logname : `logname`"
fi
```

I guess in the `if` you want to check if the logname command returns anything (when it's not?). If it is, then print it.

`test -n` checks if the next argument is an empty string.

Comment: it prints - logname: no login name